# Assignment of array to JSON key in python creates invalid JSON

Tags: python, json

I am having trouble (I'm a beginner in python) to assign an array to JSON.
For example, while using python console it works fine -

```
>>> data = [
...         "byte_array_format",
...         "auto_timer",
...         "auto_calc",
...         "auto_intense",
...         "auto_balance"]
>>> print(data)
['byte_array_format', 'auto_timer', 'auto_calc', 'auto_intense', 'auto_balance']
>>> json_db = {}
>>> json_db["value"] = data
>>> print(json_db)
{'value': ['byte_array_format', 'auto_timer', 'auto_calc', 'auto_intense', 'auto_balance']}
```

While the same thing when I'm doing with python code, it is putting a single quote for the square braces.

```
json_obj = json.dumps(unique_ids)
print(json_obj)

["byte_array_format", "auto_timer", "auto_calc", "auto_intense", "auto_balance"]
```

adding the `json_obj` to `value` add a single quote for the square braces, which ends up as invalid JSON.

```
final_json = {}
final_json["value"] = json_obj
print(final_json)

{'value': '["byte_array_format", "auto_timer", "auto_calc", "auto_intense", "auto_balance"]'}
```

Comment: `json.dumps` creates a string (that's the "s" in dumps) so you've created a string, then assigned it to an object, and wondered why you have a string there :)

Comment: great, thanks. The `value` required with double quote for a valid JSON. Any other option without json.dump()

Comment: What id your desired output?

Comment: @meAbab `{"value": json_obj}` is not valid JSON -- you haven't asked it to be. If that's what you want, why not dump `final_json`?

Comment: I'm actually waiting for a json as 
```{"value": ["byte_array_format", "auto_timer", "auto_calc", "auto_intense", "auto_balance"]}```

where `["byte_array_format", "auto_timer", "auto_calc", "auto_intense", "auto_balance"]` is a json object and would like to assign it into a json key `value` with double quote

with json.dumps() it set quote on every elements.

Comment: Ok, I've found it. 
`json.dumps({"value": ["byte_array_format", "auto_timer", "auto_calc", "auto_intense", "auto_balance"]})`
Many thanks Adam Smith